# How to extract multiple patterns from txt doc

Tags: php, regex, email, url, preg-match-all

I have a text document that lists urls with their subject and an email address. I need to extract all urls with their subject and the email address and put this all into a csv file. I just need to know how I can use regex to do this. Currently I am able to extract all urls but I need the email and subject associated with them. This is what I am working with so far:

```
$file=file_get_contents('/data/urls.txt');
$pattern='([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9+.-]{1,120}:[A-Za-z0-9/](([A-Za-z0-9$_.+!*,;/?:@&~=-])|%   [A-Fa-f0-9]{2}){1,333}(#([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9$_.+!*,;/?:@&~=%-]{0,1000}))?)';
preg_match_all($pattern, $file, $matches);

$matches=array_unique($matches[0]);

print_r($matches);
```

File structure:

Subject: URL

Email: someemail@email.com

Source URL: http://www.google.com

Comment: Can you show your txt file structure? How does data stored in it?

Answer (score 1):

How about this regular expression?

```
$pattern='/(Subject: (.*)\n\nEmail: (.*)\n\nSource URL: (.*))/';
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work for you, it depends how you are applying the term 'unique' to your input.

```
// reformat file
$pattern = '/Subject: (.*)[\n\r]+Email: (.*)[\n\r]+Source URL: (.*)[\n\r]*/';
$replace = '$1, $2, $3'."\n";
$output = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $input);

// filter unique
$arr = explode("\n", $output);
$arr = array_unique($arr);

// output
$f = fopen('path.csv', 'w');
foreach($arr as $a) {
    fwrite($f, $a);
}
fclose($f);
```